# Returning a blank cell if another is blank with formula already present in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I've got this system here where I'm tallying up a score difference.
Here is the formula I have for this cell:

```
=IF(SUM(P6:X6)>0,Y5-Z5,N5-O5)
```

The thing is when there is no sum (as in the cells in the formula are blank), I'm left with the 0 in this cell and I'm wanting it to just be blank like the others. The only thing is the cells it is referring to are formulas themselves, so when I've tried to do ISBLANK and such it didn't work. I want it to check whether Y5 has a number in it. If it does, then my cell does the formula above, if not, then returns blank. The only other thing is I need it to be able to state 0 as well so simply hiding 0 won't work. I'm confused as to how I can get that to do it, I'm sure there's a way though.

If it helps to understand, I'm doing a golf scoresheet. The cell in question is the total score. So could be -10 or 0 or 20. Y5 is the total strokes. I'm wanting the cell to be blank if nothing is on the scorecard. But I also need it to be able to say 0 if the score actually goes 0. P-X column is holes 10-18. The reason "(P6:X6)>0" is there, so the score only reflects holes 10-18 if those were played, whereas it will show the score relative for the first 9 holes instead if not. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you want to get with a few different scenarios? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed through lots of trial and error to solve it myself. Thanks to all those that posted.
Here was what I came up with which seems to work well:

```
=IF(SUM(P8:X8)>0,SUM(Y7-AA7), IF(SUM(E8:M8)>0,SUM(N7-O7),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use ISNUMBER() for your Y5 cell.

Then, if TRUE, you use the formula.
Else, you return "".

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Y5),IF(SUM(P6:X6)>0,Y5-Z5,N5-O5),""))
```

Is that what you are aiming for ?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks, but tried that. It's just giving the popup "There's a problem with this formula"

Comment: In that case, it must be the commas. If I'm correct, the function parameters must be separated by a semicolon (;) and not by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell number format to,

```
general;general;;general
```

In fact, the number format couls be much more specific than that but you are short on details. The main point is that the third argument's format mask is blank. This halts the display of zero values.

A custom number works like this

```
<positive>;<negative>;<zero>;<text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the cases separately:

```
=IF(SUM(P6:X6)>0,IF(AND(Y5="",Z5=""),"",Y5-Z5),IF(AND(N5="",O5=""),"",N5-O5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTBLANK; it will count a cell as blank even if the cell's contents is a formula that results in blank.  The formula below has holes 1-18 in columns A-R with a total in column S. If all cells are blank, the result is blank.  If any of the cells contain numbers, the result is a number (zero, positive or negative).

> `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A2:R2)=18,"",SUM(A2:R2))`

[image]

Comment: Hi that's close. I'm wanting it though to calculate the first 9 holes total only if there is no values in the second 9 (as if someone only did half the course). But if they did do the whole 18 holes then it would calculate all 18 holes. My statement I made for it works great for what I need. I was just hoping to get a way that gets rid of the 0 if there is no value. But the 0 needs to be able to show if its the value it's given. (Because a 0 would mean you got par).

Comment: That is what this formula does; it just does it all in one column.  What would you like the result to be if some of but not all of 1-9 or 10-18 have values?  Would you prefer 3 total columns (front half, back half, full course)?

Comment: Sorry I should state that holes 1-9 are columns E-M and holes 10-18 are columns P-X. So there is a gap of 2 columns where I have front 9 score and par. That's what made this tricky is that it's split, not just 18 columns straight. And I want it to default just calculate the front 9 until a value is put into hole 10, and then it calculate a full 18. Or the countblanks. I'm trying with AND but I'm not the greatest at this.